# property() setter issues in metaclass

Tags: python, properties, metaclass

I'm trying to use `property()` in my metaclass to give a way to access/set an internal attribute. I'm using `property()` as apposed to `@property` as it's inside a metaclass and I need to apply the property to a class passed in the `__new__` method.

*This is a basic example of my code with relevant parts:*

```
def __new__(mcls, name, bases, dct, **kwargs):

    def getabstract(obj):
        return getattr(obj, '_abstract', False)


    def setabstract(obj, value):
        if str(value) in ('True', 'False'):
            return setattr(obj, '_abstract', value)
        else: print(f'invalid abstract assignment {value}')
        return None        

    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, dct)

    for name, value in cls.__dict__.items():
        if callable(value):
            # only applies to callable (method)
            value._abstract = getattr(value, '_abstract', False)
            # add an _abstract attribute to the method or return its
            # current value if it already has one

    for base in bases:
        base._abstract = getattr(base, '_abstract', False)
        # give each base class an _abstract attribute if not already given

    cls.abstract = property(getabstract(cls),
                            setabstract(cls, getattr(cls, '_abstract', False)))
    # make an abstract property for class
    for name, value in cls.__dict__.items():
        if callable(value):
            # make an abstract property for functions
            value.abstract = property(getabstract(value),
                                      setabstract(value, getattr(value, '_abstract', False)))
```

When I run this, no errors occur, but when accessing a new class made by this metaclass e.g. `Foo.abstract` it returns:

```
    <property object at 0x.....>
```

Also, the `setabstract()` function used as the setter only sets the attribute if it's either `True` or `False`, but when I do something like `Foo.abstract = 'foo'`, it still sets the value to `'foo'`

Is there something I'm doing wrong here or something I've missed?

Comment: Update: Removing the use of properties and simply renaming the `_abstract` attribute to `abstract` seems to do the job, but just losing the functionality of only allowing `True/False` if setting the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A property is not an instance attribute, it is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#definition-and-introduction) attribute of the class which is bound to the object which accessed it. Here is a simplified example:

```
class A:
    @property
    def x(self):
        return True

print(A.x) # <property object at 0x0000021AE2944548>
print(A().x) # True
```

When getting `A.x`, you obtain the unbound property. When getting `A().x`, the property is bound to an instance and the `A.x.__get__` returns a value.

### Back to your code

What this means is that a property *must be a class attribute*, not an instance attribute. Or, in your case, the property must be a *metaclass* attribute.

```
class Meta(type):
    @property
    def abstract(cls):
        return getattr(cls, '_abstract', False)

    @abstract.setter
    def abstract(cls, value):
        if value in (True, False):
            setattr(cls, '_abstract', value)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'invalid abstract assignment {value}')

class Foo(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

print(Foo.abstract) # False
Foo.abstract = 'Not at bool' # TypeError: invalid abstract assignment Not at bool
```

Although, this only partially solves your issue as you want every method of you classes to have an `abstract` property. To do so, you will need *their class* to have that `property`.

Before we go any deeper, let me recall you one key concept in Python: *we're all consenting adults here*. Maybe you should just trust your users not to set `abstract` to anything else than a `bool` and let it be a non-property attribute. In particular, any user can change the `_abstract` attribute itself anyway.

If that does not suit you and you want abstract to be a `property`, then one way to do that is to define a wrapper class for methods that hold that `property`.

```
class Abstract:
    @property
    def abstract(cls):
        return getattr(cls, '_abstract', False)

    @abstract.setter
    def abstract(cls, value):
        if value in (True, False):
            setattr(cls, '_abstract', value)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'invalid abstract assignment {value}')

class AbstractCallable(Abstract):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.callable = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.callable(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta(type, Abstract):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, dct, **kwargs):
        for name, value in dct.items():
            if callable(value):
                dct[name] = AbstractCallable(value)

        return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, dct)

class Foo(metaclass=Meta):
    def bar(self):
        pass

print(Foo.abstract) # False
print(Foo.bar.abstract) # False
Foo.bar.abstract = 'baz' # TypeError: invalid abstract assignment baz
```